# sigmoid() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x

Why am I getting this error

> sigmoid() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

while using function yHat = NN.forward(X)??

```
class Neural_Networks(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inputLayerSize =2
        self.outputLayerSize =1
        self.hiddenLayerSize = 3
        #weights
        self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputLayerSize, self.hiddenLayerSize)
        self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenLayerSize, self.outputLayerSize)

    def forward(self,X):
        #propogates input through network
        self.z2 = np.dot(X, self.W1)
        self.a2 = self.sigmoid( self.z2 )
        self.Z3 = np.dot(self.a2,self.W2)
        yHat = self.sigmoid(self.z3)
        return yHat

    def sigmoid(z):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
```

Comment: Add `self` as first argument of `sigmoid` or add the `@staticmethod` decorator over it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using it as an instance method so you must include `self` as the first argument

```
class Neural_Networks(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inputLayerSize =2
        self.outputLayerSize =1
        self.hiddenLayerSize = 3
        #weights
        self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputLayerSize, self.hiddenLayerSize)
        self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenLayerSize, self.outputLayerSize)

    def forward(self,X):
        #propogates input through network
        self.z2 = np.dot(X, self.W1)
        self.a2 = self.sigmoid( self.z2 )
        self.Z3 = np.dot(self.a2,self.W2)
        yHat = self.sigmoid(self.z3)
        return yHat

    def sigmoid(self, z):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
```

Conversely if you want to use `sigmoid` as a class method than you'll need to add a `@staticmethod` decorator to it eg:

```
@staticmethod
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
```

Making it a static method is likely the right option since you don't use self in the method.